# Проблемы с кирилицей в CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, bat

Имею английскую версию Windows 10.

Создаю батник в кодировке OEM 866 и засовываю туда серию команд на создание директорий.

В итоге у меня создают директории с ироглифами там, где была кирилица.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

На работе стоит русская версия Windows 7 и сохранение батника в кодировке OEM866 работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписка в коментариях выяснила, что надо поменять кодировку (кодовую страницу) в самом скрипте через команду `chcp`. Предлагался вариант с

```
chcp 1251
```

но помог

```
chcp 866
```